# FORTRAN Array miscalculation

Tags: arrays, linux, fortran

So I've been checking some calculation issues in values of a equation of state simulator.
After some checking I saw that the module constantes does not drag the values into the subroutines declared at the start of it. I do not want to declare those variables every time I use them, what should I do? Declare a subroutine with the values and "use" it every time I need the parameters?

```
MODULE Constantes
Implicit None
!Lista de constantes para funciones a y b usadas para calcular Z
!Real,dimension(4)::y
!Real::T,P
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::Tc=(/ 190.56, 132.85, 304.12, 126.2 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::Pc=(/ 45.992, 34.94, 73.74, 33.98 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::w=(/ 0.011, 0.045, 0.225, 0.037 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::na=(/ 0.072, 0.608, 0.974, 25765.2 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::ma=(/15.68, 9.62, 34.04, 0.00 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::ba=(/ 6.48, 66.2, 14.04, 0.000928699 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::da=(/ 0.025, 0.03, 0.061, 0.00 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::ha=(/30.56, 48.16, 34.67, 30.0 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::ua=(/ 13.45, 14.84, 20.79, 0.0 /)
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::ka=(/ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.13 /)
Real,Parameter::c0=0.48,c1=1.574,c2=-0.176,eps=1,sig=0
Double Precision,Parameter::omega=0.08664035,psi=0.42748023
!Variables input para constante A
!Variables input para A y B
Contains
Subroutine CA(y,T,At,ap,aij,D,n) 
      Implicit None
    Double precision::psi 
Double precision,intent(out)::At,D
    Double Precision,Dimension(4),intent(out)::ap
    Double Precision,Dimension(4,4),intent(out)::aij
    Real,Dimension(4)::Tc,Pc,w
    Real::c0,c1,c2
    Double precision,intent(in)::T,n
    Double precision,dimension(4),intent(in)::y
    Integer::i,j
    Do i=1, 4 !Array de constantes a individuales
        ap(i)=Tc(i)*Tc(i)
        !ap(i)=(psi*(83.14*83.14*Tc(i)*Tc(i))/Pc(i))!*((1+((c0+c1*w(i)+c2*w(i)*w(i))*(1-sqrt(T/Tc(i)))))**(2))         
    End do
    Do i=1,4
        Do j=1,4
            aij(i,j)=y(i)*y(j)*sqrt(ap(i)*ap(j))!Constantes duales de a
        End do 
    End Do 
    At=sum(sum(aij,dim=1)) !A total independiente de n
    D=At*n*n !A total dependiente de n
   End Subroutine CA
   Subroutine CB(y,Bt,bi,B,bij,n)
   Implicit none
   Real,Dimension(4)::Tc,Pc
   Double precision, intent(in)::n
   Double Precision,Dimension(4),intent(out)::bi
   Double precision,dimension(4),intent(in)::y
Double precision::omega,bm
Double precision,intent(out)::Bt,B
    Double precision,Dimension(4,4),intent(out)::bij
Integer::i,j
    Do i=1,4 !Array de constantes b individuales
        bi(i)=omega*83.14*Tc(i)/Pc(i)
    End Do
    Do i=1,4 !Array constantes duales de b
        Do j=1,4
            bij(i,j)=0.5*(bi(i)+bi(j))
        End Do
    End Do
    BT=sum(bi*y) !B total independiente de n
    B=n*BT !b total dependiente de n
End Subroutine CB
END MODULE Constantes
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem you have is that you re-declare (at least some of) the parameter arrays inside the subroutine.  For example, the line

```
Real,Dimension(4)::Tc,Pc,w
```

masks the existence of the module variables such as

```
Real,Parameter,Dimension(4)::Tc=(/ 190.56, 132.85, 304.12, 126.2 /)
```

The subroutine already has access to those parameter arrays by *host-association*, declaring them again inside the subroutine is an error in this case.

Some would argue that you should, even when it is not strictly necessary, pass all arguments to procedures through their argument lists.